# How to add URL Polyfill in Angular App

Tags: angular, polyfills

We would like to use https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt in our application. And right now it says, Internet Explorer 11 support requires a [URL polyfill](https://github.com/github/url-polyfill).
Need help or steps in order to add this polyfill in the Angular App.

Answer (score 12):

1. Ensure you have the Angular CLI in your computer installed globally if you don't already:

   ```
   npm install -g @angular/cli
   ```
2. `cd` to your project root (the directory with `package.json` in)
3. Install the URL polyfill (the `--save` adds the polyfill to your `package.json` file):

   ```
   npm install url-polyfill --save
   ```
4. Open the Angular `polyfills.ts` file and after the line with "`/** IE10 and IE11 requries...`" add this line:

   ```
   import 'url-polyfill';
   ```

Comment: Does it support Node 10+ ?

Comment: @ShobhitVerma Node.js 10 already supports `URL` (see https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/url.html ) so you **do not** need to use `url-polyfill` for server-side JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

[The official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support) describes the necessary steps.

What you must do is:

1. install the npm package
2. import the file in polyfills.ts